# Celsius is always 0.0?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm making a simple temperature conversion program in Java that converts Fahrenheit to Celsius.  My program compiles just fine, but no matter what number I input, it always says that Celsius is 0.0!  What could I be doing wrong?  Here is my full code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FahrenheitToCelsius {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double fahrenheit, celsius;

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the temperature in Fahrenheit:");

    fahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(input.trim());

    celsius = (5 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The temperature is " + celsius + " degrees celsius.");

    }

}
```

Comment: What value does this produce: `(5 / 9)` ?  Print out the result of that computation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because (5 / 9) = 0.

5 and 9 are both `ints`, and `int` division here will result in 0 (5/9 = 0.555..., which can't be an `int` so it is truncated to 0). Use doubles (5.0 / 9.0) and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
 celsius = (5 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);
```

5 and 9 are both integer constants, which means that the calculated value will be truncated to 0.

Try instead:

```
celsius = (5.0 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting `0` cause `5 / 9` is always `0`.

What you can do something like this

```
celsius = ((fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0) / 9.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
celsius = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
```

The reason this works has to do with how the operands are grouped.  In `fahrenheit - 32`, `fahrenheit` is a `double` and `32` is an `int`, so the `32` gets *promoted* to a `double`, and the result is a `double`.  Then, in:

```
(fahrenheit - 32) * 5
```

`(fahrenheit - 32)` is a `double` (see above), and `5` is an `int`, so the `5` gets promoted to a `double` and the resulting multiplication is a `double`.  Again:

```
((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9
```

Now `(fahrenheit - 32) * 5` is a `double`, as we saw above, and `9` is an `int`, so the `9` gets promoted, and we end up with double-precision floating-point division.

By contrast:

```
celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9);
```

The operands of `/`, 5 and 9, are both `int`.  So there's no promotion, and the program performs *integer division*, with an `int` result.  The result will therefore be 0.  Now, since `fahrenheit - 32` is a `double`, the `0` will be promoted to a `double`--but of course it's too late.

The point is that the Java compiler is not a mind-reader; even though the two expressions look the same mathematically, the compiler has a very specific method in which it does things, and programmers must be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks, I already fixed it.